# How do you define an index in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, post

Using firebug I keep getting an 'undefined index' notice for 'item', 'rating', and 'classes'. Below is my code. In the php code if I comment out the if/die statement that's where I get 'undefined index' from, if I leave the if/die statement in I get 'There was a problem' as the response with firebug. My question is how do you properly define an index? What I'm wanting to do is transfer some values using the POST method to a different PHP file. If I alter the Javascript code to make sure up to that point is good, everything looks good, but when it gets to the next stage, which is the php code below, that's where my problem occurs. BTW, I'm not a programmer and pretty new with this stuff, this is just a side project. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
<?php
require_once("classes/include.all.php");

// Check that the data was sent

if (sizeof($_POST) == 0
|| $_POST['item'] == null
|| strlen(trim($_POST['item'])) == 0
|| $_POST['rating'] == null
|| strlen(trim($_POST['rating'])) == 0
|| is_numeric($_POST['rating'])
|| $_POST['classes'] == null
|| strlen(trim($_POST['classes'])) == 0)
 {
    die("There was a problem");
  }


 echo Rating::RateItem($_POST['item'], $_POST['rating'], $_POST['classes']);

?>
```

Javascript code

```
function RateItem(varItemId, varRate)
{

var varorgclass = document.getElementById(varItemId).className;

var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  request=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  request=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
request.open("POST","ajax.rate.item.php",true);
//request.onload= ReloadRating;
request.setRequestHeader('item',varItemId);
request.setRequestHeader('rating',varRate);
request.setRequestHeader('classes',varorgclass);
request.send();
```

Comment: The existing answers seem to be assuming you don't understand what is causing the error message, but I think you do.  Your Javascript is probably causing the error due to a browser inconsistency or something like that.  There is a great, very easy to use library called JQuery you can use that will help with tasks like this one.  Check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those values aren't set, there is a problem in your javascript, which may be because of a browser incompatibility.  Since you are new, I would strongly recommend the use of JQuery - it's easy to use, lightweight, and portable.  You can use Google's hosted copy of JQuery for quick access that will already be cached by most people, too.

**First, include this in the head of your HTML/PHP Document:**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Then, use the following javascript in place of your current "request" setup:**

```
$.ajax({
    url:"ajax.rate.item.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:{item:varItemId,rating:varRate,classes:varorgclass},
    success:function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

On `$_POST['item'] == null` (in the first if mentioned in the question) the warning appears because `$_POST['item']` does not exist.

You can prevent this by either:

```
isset($_POST['item'])
```

first, or

```
array_key_exists('item', $_POST)
```

Or.... you disable `error_reporint()` for `E_WARNING` / `E_NOTICE`.

First solution recommended.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The answer you gave was part of my problem also, and helped me to get it resolved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable are not set, try this :

```
<?php
require_once("classes/include.all.php");

// Check that the data was sent
if (isset($_POST['item'], $_POST['rating'], $_POST['classes'])) {
if (sizeof($_POST) == 0
|| $_POST['item'] == null
|| strlen(trim($_POST['item'])) == 0
|| $_POST['rating'] == null
|| strlen(trim($_POST['rating'])) == 0
|| is_numeric($_POST['rating'])
|| $_POST['classes'] == null
|| strlen(trim($_POST['classes'])) == 0)
 {
    die("There was a problem");
  }


 echo Rating::RateItem($_POST['item'], $_POST['rating'], $_POST['classes']);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `!empty($_POST['item'])` for the three of your variables.